# Visual Studio C# Form Designer not Allowing me to Select Elements

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm fairly new to C#, I'm following along with an online tutorial, and I was working on building some forms when I noticed that the Visual Studio 2019 C# Form Designer was acting strangely. First every once in a while I would place an element on the form and then I wouldn't be able to select any other element, it would be stuck on that one element and clicking at all would cause the selected element to resize, rather than move like I would expect. That was annoying, but I was able to close the design window, and reopen it and it worked okay again, until it happened again usually after placing 2 or 3 elements with no issue.

But then a new problem started happening, where the place that I click on the design is offset to the left and down. So In order to select an element I have to move to the right and up, in order to be able to select the element I want to edit. The red rectangle in the picture below shows the spot where I would have to click in order to select the "Create Tournament" label. This is much worse than the first problem, and closing and reopening the design window doesn't help, nor does restarting Visual Studio or even resetting my computer. This is also happening across all of my forms. I was wondering if anyone knew what was going on or how I could fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Comment: I would strongly suggest opening the window "Document Outline" from menu View -> Other Windows.  It lets you manage your form elements without depending on being able to click them in the form designer.  Even when everything is working perfectly, you can still find yourself in situations where you can't select a specific control.  And yeah, the form designer is kind of buggy in this way.

Comment: It seems that you are creating a Winforms with target framework `.NET Core 3.1` or `.NET 5.0`. The corresponding `Winforms Designer` is still under development. You can  report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8). And try to create a Winfoms with `.NET Framework`.